# How to keep the document status as Checked out when it is uploading to sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint

how to keep the document status as Checked out when it is uploading to sharepoint site?
Means , I want that , when i will insert any document to specific document library of sharepoint site , then how shold i can keep its status as Checked out rather than checked by default

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by adding a [SPItemEventReceiver.ItemCheckedIn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemcheckedin.aspx) Event handler for the check in event. Add code to automatically [checkout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.checkout%28v=office.12%29.aspx) the item again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how to use SPItemEventReceiver.ItemCheckedIn in workflow ?? how to inherit workflow from SPItemEventReceiver?